# Installation of .c files in phylip

Tags: package-management, software-installation, make, makefile

I am trying to install .C functions of PHYLIP in Linux/ubuntu. I read documentation and it mentioned it is very easy compilation and of .C functions:

> To make executables, use your C compiler. It is probably as simple as
>   going into the src directory, copying Makefile.unix and calling the
>   copy Makefile, and then typing the command make install

I just have Makefile.unx in the folder. Not any Configure.* files.

What exactly means this phrase? **copying Makefile.unix and calling the copy Makefile** Maybe it is very clear but I am new in Linux, sorry.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I would interpret that as meaning you should perform the commands

```
cp Makefile.unix Makefile
make
```

Alternatively, you could use the Makefile.unix directly, *without* the extra step of copying it, by using the `-f` option

```
make -f Makefile.unix
```

Comment: I tried both but no good result:

Comment: alireza@unix-laptop:~/Downloads/phylip-3.695/src$make -f Makefile.unix                make: Makefile.unix: No such file or directory make: *** No rule to make target `Makefile.unix'. Stop.

Comment: alireza@unix-laptop:~/Downloads/phylip-3.695/src$ make           make: *** No targets specified and no makefile found. Stop.

Comment: Well, is the file called Makefile.unix or Makefile.unx? Your original post is unclear. If the file is Makefile.unx (without the i) then adjust the command accordingly.

Comment: no it is with i, because of that I run:  make -f Makefile.unix

Comment: in help file of package they explained and named the fine just .unx, but I found the file with .unix in src